# How to avoid ambiguous constructor error when providing bool and double overloads

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading

I'm building an class whose instances can represent multiple simple value types. It has an interface that looks roughly like this:

```
class value {

  public:

    value();
    explicit value( double value );
    explicit value( bool value );

 ...
}
```

I'm finding that I can't construct it in the way I was hoping because integer numbers (a very common use case) are considered ambiguous between bool and double.

```
value bool_value( true );   // OK
value pi_approx( 3.14159 ); // OK
value int_value( 42 );      // ERROR: ambiguous constructor
```

Is there any way to make this work without requiring callers to use a decimal point for numeric values or using explicit "make" static functions?

[EDIT]: This class represents values from a JSON parse tree, so the distinction between bool and number is significant and must be preserved.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to have a constructor that takes an `int` and just delegates to the one that takes a `double`?

Comment: See edit above: The distinction between bool and number is significant and must be preserved.

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of your edit is. I think it was already obvious that the distinction between bools and numbers is important, and no one was suggesting otherwise.

Comment: @ruakh: I originally thought that some were suggesting that bool could be collapsed into a number without loss of semantics.

Answer (score 4):

You should point, that it's double, or bool in this case. Something like

```
value int_value(static_cast<double>(42));
```

or simply write constructor, that should receive integer value.

Problem is, that compiler has two variants for construct object, one is convert integer to `double` and second is convert integer to `bool`, no one is worth than another, so, compiler cannot choose, without help to it.

Comment: It seems to make it more transparent, you'd want the integer constructor, with a fairly permissive integer type (eg. `long long int`).  That'd capture the widest range of integers, and avoid requiring the user to write the ugly cast at every point it appears.

Comment: Thinking this through overnight (sleep always helps, doesn't it?), I think the approach I'll take will be to have named factory methods instead of an overloaded constructor

Comment: See edit above: The distinction between bool and number is semantically important. It would not be OK to have bools collapsed into numbers.

Comment: Adding an integer constructor does not help. The ambiguous constructor error still occurs, this time citing all three constructors (`bool`, `int64_t`, and `double`) as candidates.

Comment: As to @ForEveR's solution, I would prefer not to impose the explicit cast requirement on this object's constructor's callers.

Answer (score 2):

It appears it's not possible to have the compiler automatically disambiguate the constructors in the way I had hoped.

I have worked around this by using factory methods instead:

```
class value {
  public:
    static value from_double( double value );
    static value from_int64( int64_t value );
    static value from_bool( bool value );
  ...
}
```